# Leaking valve hole

Tags: tire, tubeless, valves

I tried different valves with no luck and used gorilla tape for inner wheel so I don’t think it’s the valves and I’ve taped it making sure.

I’ve covered all the holes.   I am at my wits end with tubeless.

---

How can I methodically figure out why my tubeless MTB rim is leaking air?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Are you asking about a tubeless setup?

Comment: Are your rims and tyres designed to be tubeless or is this a ghetto-tubeless ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a large tub that will hold water?  Inflate your tubeless tyre, and submerge a length of the rim in water.

There should be a stream of bubbles leaving the area where your leak is located.   Avoid submerging the whole rim because it's not good for the hub, but anything up to 7/16ths of the rim at once should help.

The downside is that sometimes air leaks can travel which can be confusing.